# Set RootViewController in UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode6

Currently i working on iOS App and my requirement is to set TabbarController as a root view controller in all the upcoming features ViewController. so anyone can please suggest me how it possible ?

This my TabBarController
[image]

and this was Viewcontroller for Edit Profile which is outside viewcontroller means not in mention 5 tabs viewcontroller.so i wanted to to Display in bottom of controller TabbarViewController as a root viewcontroller.
[image]

Comment: Do you means when press `Edit profile`, push to your `Edit Table View Controller `?

Comment: Please share me suggestion if you've..Thank You

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Comment: Yes i appreciate your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, that's simple.

First, you should embed in a `UINavigationController` to your `Middle View Controller`.

Then, you can push `Edit Table View Controller` when press `edit button`

Here is an overview :

I only add two controller into `tabbarController` you can add five controllers.

[image]

Comment: yes that is the answer which i want .. Thank You Jacky